# Is [NSManagedObjectContext save] an atomic commit when using an underlying SQLite DB?

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, sqlite, core-data

Or could it be that Core Data splits the save operation into several sequential atomic steps? For my work, I have to be sure that when re-accessing the database after a crash, either everything was saved, or I'm rolled back to the state before the save operation. I must not have the case where some modified NSObject's were saved but some not.

NB: I'm using the following SQLite pragma options (do I need any others to ensure atomicity?):

```
[pragmaOptions setObject:@"FULL" forKey:@"synchronous"];
[pragmaOptions setObject:@"1" forKey:@"fullfsync"];
[pragmaOptions setObject:@"WAL" forKey:@"journal_mode"];
```

Comment: Do you know you can see the SQL statements in the console when you pass `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` as argument to the executable (Edit Scheme -> arguments tab)?

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful! Inspecting the log after saving with two modified objects shows that these are committed atomically. Let's hope that it's the same even for dozens of modified objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Core Data’s `-save` is transactional. Either everything gets saved or nothing. That's true regardless of which store you use.

Comment: Is this cited in the documentation? I was unable to find it.